# Asynchrone sequence in nodejs with multiple levels

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I'm struggling trying to have a javascript asynchrone sequence, although I have seen a lot of tutorials online.
Maybe you could help me :-)

- I have an array of 6 functions (F1..F6)
- Those function needs to be ran sequentially, forwarding a shared parameter from one function to the other.
- And inside F3, I wanted to call another little function multiple times (currently using an array.map) ==> let's call them F3a, F3b, F3c
- F3a, F3b, F3c needs to be sequential as well ; at least F4 must start **AFTER all** F3 are completed - and still those multilevel function are sharing the same global parameter.
- I'm not sure I understand the full concept of Promises but I bet I need to learn more on them. :-)

The expected scheme I have in mind:

```
F1---|
******F2------|
***************F3a-|
********************F3b-|
*************************F3c-|
******************************F4------|
******************************F5------|
******************************F6------|
```

It might looks easy for all of you, but as a non developer, it's a bit harder for me to have the code working.
I have something partially working (using async and some Promises) and I guess (not sure) it is on the following sequencing; so not as expected :

```
F1---|
******F2------|
***************F3a-|
***************F3b-|
***************F3c-|
********************F4------|
********************F5------|
********************F6------|
```

I can't really show you the current code ; it's a total mess and I'd prefer to explain you the idea rather than getting the solution from you.

Should I use a nodejs library or should I code it using native js? Any library suggestion?
Any thought?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: FYI, requests for library suggestions are off topic at Stack Overflow.  If you can't show the current code, then rewrite it as a minimal reproducible example (the exercise will be good for you, and helps to make the question self contained.)  Meanwhile, consider `Promise.all(F3a,F3b,F3c).then(F4).`

Comment: "*I guess (not sure) it is on the following sequencing*" - we can't tell without seeing the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this without any external library

```
const sharedVariable = {}

async function doTask(data) {
  const data1 = await f1(data, sharedVariable);
  const data2 = await f2(data1, sharedVariable);
  const data3 = await f3(data2, sharedVariable);
  const data4 = await f4(data3, sharedVariable);
  const data5 = await f5(data4, sharedVariable);
  const data6 = await f6(data5, sharedVariable);

  return data6;
}

async function f3(data) {
  const data1 = await f3a(data, sharedVariable);
  const data2 = await f3b(data1, sharedVariable);
  const data3 = await f3c(data2, sharedVariable);

  return data3;
}

doTask();
```

Comment: `ret.resolve(data3)` doesn't work. And why are you using `async`/`await` in one function but `.then()` in the other?

Comment: @Bergi refactored it a bit

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure I understand the full concept of Promises but I bet I need to learn more on them. :-)

Yes, go ahead! What you describe is really easy to do using promises with `async`/`await` syntax:

```
async function f3(arg) {
  await f3a();
  await f3b();
  await f3c();
  return res;
}

async function main(val) {
  await f6(await f5(await f4(await f3(await f2(await f1(val))))));
}
```

You can also easily use an actual loop if you have the functions in an array:

```
async function main(val) {
  for (const f of fs)
    val = await f(val);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[d3-queue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3-queue) does a pretty good job for me. I also used it to create multiple nested queues. The API's easy to understand.

in your case it can look like this:

```js
// all functions f1-f6 should have the same signarure
// function fN(sharedPArameter, done) ...
// done - is a callback you should call when done

function F3(sharedParameter, done) {
   let nestedQ = d3.queue(1);
   nestedQ.defer(f3a, sharedParameter);
   nestedQ.defer(f3b, sharedParameter);
   nestedQ.defer(f3c, sharedParameter);
   nestedQ.awaitAll(error => {
      done(error);
   });
}

let q = d3.queue(1); // put 1 for sequential execution

q.defer(f1, sharedParameter);
q.defer(f2, sharedParameter);
q.defer(f3, sharedParameter);
q.defer(f4, sharedParameter);

q.awaitAll((error, result) => {
   // when everything's done
});
```